# Why Spring REST do not analyze "get","post" methods with same url

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using spring rest , I have two methods

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object test1(HttpServletRequest request) {}

@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object test2(HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

But it is not able to detect the two methods. Is it necessary that the URL should be different for each http method in spring.

Comment: Spring can differentiate GET and POST with the same url.

Comment: if you're not hitting either method, then it's highly likely you're not requesting the correct url. Do you have a requestmapping at the controller level, how is your DispatchServlet mapping in web.xml, what are the actual urls being requested

Comment: I had this problem too. When I changed the get to another url it worked, so it does not work always...

Answer (score 3):

Spring can support GET and POST for the same url. I've done it many times. For example (this is POST and PUT, but it's the same difference):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="player")
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Player createNewPlayer(@RequestBody Player player) {
        return playerService.createNewPlayer(player);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Player updatePlayer(@RequestBody Player player) {
        return playerService.updatePlayer(player);
    }
}
```

If you can post the error message you're getting, maybe we can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Corinthian type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Comment: Funny typo of my screen name. It is actually a fake Corinthian name I made up. Anyway, when do you get that message? Is that on start up, or when you try to hit a url? What url are you using?

Comment: I am using the url just @RequestMapping("/"), and it comes when I try to hit the URL.

Comment: I am using the url just @RequestMapping("/"), and it comes when I try to hit the URL

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late but i might be useful for someone who still wants to know this concept. In below code we will be getting the error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping.Cannot map 'XXX' method.**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object test1(HttpServletRequest request) {}

@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object test2(HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

this error occurs because RequestHandlerMapper delegates the request on the basis of pattern of URL only and not on the method type.Hence if we have the same URL pattern, handlermapping will fail to distinguish that to which method it should map because of ambiguity.